# Render swf to png or other image format

Tags: linux, image, png, flash, converters

How can I, on linux, render a swf to a image file?
I need to be able to load other swfs into that swf and run actionscript code.

Is it even possible on linux? I need to do it from PHP, it's fine if I have to use command-line tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SWF to PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001946/convert-swf-to-png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`swfrender` from [swftools](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Swfrender) works for basic SWF files.

`swfdec-thumbnailer` from [swfdec-gnome](http://swfdec.freedesktop.org/wiki/) works though it only gets the first frame of the swf.

To get any frame from swf using swfdec see the C code snippet in the following mailing list [post](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/swfdec/2008-October/002045.html).

`gnash` from [gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) also works `gnash -s<scale-image-factor> --screenshot last --screenshot-file output.png -1 -r1 input.swf`, last image of the swf.

`ffmpeg` from [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) also works for some swf formats `ffmpeg -i movie.swf -f image2 -vcodec png movie%d.png`

Also see the following [guide](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2010/11/02/server-side-rendering-of-swf-images-using-gnash/) for a commandline pipeline.

In order to call external programs from php you use the `exec` command documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Note that for security reasons it is important to escape arguments passed to `exec` with another command like `escapeshellcmd` or `escapeshellarg` for security reasons.

Once you have converted to an image format whether for single frame or all frame, you can't run action script. Other non GNU / Linux tools support the export of the action script from from SWF.

If the SWF that you are exporting to PNG is too complicated for the other tools than you can use the Flash Plugin or `Gnash` and `Xvfb` along with screen capture software to capture either image frames of the SWF or a video format like avi. Then you can extract the images from the video format.

This virtual framebuffer method will support complicated SWF files, though it requires a lot of work as you need to use either Gnash and Xvfb and Screen Capture, or a browser , Xvfb and Selenium, if you want to capture a certain set of mouse / keyboard interactions with the SWF.

Gnash with and without the Virtual FrameBuffer should load the ActionScript before exporting, but may have issues with complicated ActionScript. Flash Plugin with Virtual Framebuffer will load the ActionScript before exporting.

Also see the following StackOverFlow questions, which you question is a duplicate of

- [Convert SWF to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001946/convert-swf-to-png)
- [Render Flash (SWF) frame as image (PDF,PNG,JPG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988823/render-flash-swf-frame-as-image-pdf-png-jpg)
- [SWF to image (jpg, png, …) with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245896/swf-to-image-jpg-png-with-php)

Comment: Except I require that the actionscript in the swf can run, I know for a fact that swfrender doesn't work for what I want. Do the others allow actionscript to run?

Comment: Once exported to png, the resulting png images or mng animations can't run actionscript regardless of the tool used.

Comment: No, I mean that before the flash movie is exported it needs to run code to display what I want.

Comment: @Appleman1234: Great advice. Any hints, how to render from SWF to PDF? I can do it via image, but it would be nice to transform fonts & labels as "text" into PDF, without rasterising.

Comment: Normally a separate question is supposed to be a separate question, as far as I know there is no way to convert SWF to PDF without rastering to images without using official Adobe Software, and even then they will raster to image, if the relevant mark type of text or Postscript isn't detected.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up using.

You can use a tool like [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) (X11 server) and run the standalone flash player projector inside it (you may need to install a bunch of 32-bit libraries), then use a screen capture utility like [import](http://imagemagick.org/script/import.php) to capture the screen and crop it to size.

I found [this page](http://remdex.info/How-to-make-flash-swf-screenshot-in-linux,-updated-98a.html) on rendering swf screenshots in linux helpful. It also says that you can use gnash to do this, however gnash won't work for flash player 9+.

Answer (score 1):

Try this air application http://swfrenderer.kurst.co.uk

It render swf frame by frame